# What's the best climate for the extremes of a supercontinent that doesn't exceed latitude 55 and don't have ice caps?

Tags: internal-consistency, climate, weather

The world is not to be so much different from Earth, unless it has 1.5x Earth's mass, the average temperature is 17°C and the axial tilt is 20,5°.

Comparing to Earth in this latitude, it should be Cfb/c in the west coast like in southwest Chile and northwest USA/Canada, but the central and east coast should be the same? Like in south Australia and New Zealand that is Cfb too. Even some islands in latitude 50 have this climate, but above this it changes to ET, because of Antarctica. Or should it have a warmer weather, because of the info above? (Csb/a, for example).

[image]

This is the map of the world with topography. Dark green is 0-200m, green is 200-500m, yellow is 500-1000m, light brown is 1000-1500m, brown is 1500-2500m, dark brown is 2500-3500m and red is higher than 3500m.

Dot line is the tropics and dashed line is 45°. And to be specific, the "equator" passes by the inner sea.

Comment: This will depend entirely on orogeny and oceanic currents. Siberia and Moscow are at roughly the same latitude as London, but they have wildly different climates.

Comment: @stix i updated the map with the ocean currents

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approximation of your supercontinent's climate. I've based it on the early–mid [Pliocene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pliocene_climate), which was also 2–4° warmer than today on average.

[image: Köppen climate approximation]

This reconstruction of the Pliocene biome shows temperate forest (~Dfb) and steppes (~BSk) north of 60°–

[image: Pliocene megabiomes]

—so I'd say your northern- and southernmost coasts should be warmer by a full group (C). I may be overestimating the extent of BWh/BSh here, but elevations relative to prevailing winds suggests a rainshadow effect.

Comment: Thanks, rek! This map of Pliocene biomes shows a lot of things i was hoping to find out and i liked the map you made for my world climates. Just two things i want to change or state it can work. I would like to have a rainforest in that basin in the eastern landmass, like the Congo rainforest, and if you go check it is in the wrong side of the prevailing winds too. Can it work in an Aw/s climate or even the rainforest can make the climate change to Am or Af?

Comment: The second change is about the eastern side of the mountains in the southwestern landmass, because i would like to have a "Great Plains"-like biome with a mississippi river going through it. A hot Great Plains don't bother me, but i don't know if it can happen in an arid/ semi-arid climate.

Comment: Do you mean the Aw/s basin 75% encircled by mountains just south of 0°? Flow a lot of rivers through there and I think Af would be believable. Your eastern SW is a combination of the hottest latitude and rainshadow (south of 30°), but note this is marked as 'grassland' in the Pliocene reconstruction. Stick a river there and you'll get a strip of vegetation on its banks...